# I can not create Apps and Integration Keys on Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I can not create Apps and Integration Keys on Docusign.

> Connect API key with PHP on Developer.Docusign.com, The Result is Empty. It did not connect between 2 site from Docusign.com account.

[image: Connect API key with PHP on Developer.Docusign.com, The Result is Empty. It did not connect between 2 site from Docusign.com account.]

> I found "create api button" on Developer.Docusign.com

[image: I found "create api button" on Developer.Docusign.com]

> I not found "create api button" on Docusign.com

[image: I not found "create api button" on Docusign.com]

Could you please help me check the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using production.
You can only create keys/apps in demo/developer account.
Go to https://admindemo.docusign.com/ and log in.
If you don't have an account - you need to create one which you can do [here](https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/?ga=2.70927056.1363819232.1590515244-192278368.1546193875&ECID=20890&elqCampaignId=20890&LS=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&utm_campaign=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&Channel=DDCUS000016968056&cName=DocuSign.com).

Comment: But demo/developer account not have sync data from production of DocuSign. I try to create and call with API key. It's empty. I not sure how to create the API key on the production?

Comment: you cannot do that. You have to go through a process called go-live which takes your IK from demo into production. The process requires approval based on certain criteria. But you always start in demo/developer account.

Comment: read more about go-live here - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/go-live

Comment: Yes, I mark check this to the answer. Thank you very much.